# How to 'normalise' HTML with node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to process a page with NodeJS and cheerio, but I am running into a few issues due to extra closing tags, which appears to be throwing it off. Is there any NodeJS library that I can use to first convert the page to properly formatted HTML before processing it, much in the same way as browser do?

An example of the HTML I am seeing:

```
<tr><td><a href="...">mylink</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="...">mylink</a></td></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="...">mylink</a></td></td></tr>
```

and my code:

```
var nodes = $('div table[cellpadding=3] tr td a')
```

Without the extra closing tag it returns me three anchors, but in the current scenario it only returns me one. I haven't seen any way around this in Cheerio, hence want to preprocess the HTML.

Comment: If it's consistantly the same problem, you could search and replace '</a></td></td></tr>' with '</a></td></tr>'

Comment: I am not comfortable with that approach, as that would involve code for a single use case and I would rather have a solution that I can use with other badly marked up pages, that render fine in a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some experimentation, I ended up using jsdom, taking advantage of its ability to create a DOM and also being able to serialise that document object model:

```
function processPage(data) {
    data = jsdom(data).documentElement.outerHTML
    $ = cheerio.load(data);
    ...
}
```

Note, I could probably replace cheerio with jsdom completely, but I will need to compare the feature sets first.

Answer (score 0):

You could try gulp-html-replace

```
npm i gulp-html-replace
```

More info: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-replace